# How can I UPDATE SQL using values from multiple columns of a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two tables in my SQL database:

**TableA**:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| score1 | score2 | score3 | timestamp  | identifier |
------------------------------------------------------
| NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | 2018-01-01 | ABCDEF     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

**TableB**:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| scoreA | scoreB | scoreC | timestamp  | identifier |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1234   | 5678   | 8901   | 2018-02-02 | ABCDEF     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to write an `UPDATE` query to `SELECT` and map the `scoreA, scoreB, scoreC` from **TableB** to the `score1, score2, score3` columns of **TableA** for those records matching the `identifier` value.

I can think of ways to do this in code, but not in sql. I'm trying to obtain a table (after the `UPDATE` is performed), that looks like:

**Expected** *TableA after update query*:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| score1 | score2 | score3 | timestamp  | identifier |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1234   | 5678   | 8901   | 2018-01-01 | ABCDEF     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm thinking I can do simple `SELECT` inside my `UPDATE` such (pseudo):

```
UPDATE TableA SET (
    score1 = (SELECT scoreA FROM TableB WHERE identifier = 'ABCDEF'), 
    score2 = (SELECT scoreB FROM TableB WHERE identifier = 'ABCDEF'), 
    score3 = (SELECT scoreC FROM TableB WHERE identifier = 'ABCDEF'), 
) identifier = 'ABCDEF'
```

But to me, this looks silly in that the inner `SELECTS` are basically completely redundant. **Is there a more effective way to `UPDATE` one table with `SELECT` results from another table?**

This might be a simple question, but at the moment, its over my head.

If I was doing this in code, I am using C#, although, I'm trying to do this entirely in SQL. **MS Azure SQL if it matters.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can perform the Update via a Join.  Notice the alias A.

```
Update A set score1=B.scoreA
            ,score2=B.scoreB
            ,score3=B.scoreC
 From  TableA A
 Join  TableB B on A.identifier = B.identifier
```

Comment: Yup! That did it. This is so much simpler that I was thinking it would be. Thank you for the pointers!

Comment: @Brett Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do the joins with `table1` with `table2`

```
update t1 
      set t1.score1 = t2.scoreA,
          t1.score2 = t2.scoreB,
          t1.score3 = t2.scoreC
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.identifier = t1.identifier
```

If, i would go with your way then that would *correlated* approach but not more effective

```
update t set 
         score1 = (select top 1 scoreA from table2 where identifier = t1.identifier),
         score2 = (select top 1 scoreB from table2 where identifier = t1.identifier),
         score3 = (select top 1 scoreC from table2 where identifier = t1.identifier)
from table1 t1
```